# How do I sort files into a sub-folder based on filename part?

Tags: command-line, files, mv, patterns

These are the files in the directory:

```
Ford-Mustang-001.jpg
Ford-Mustang-002.jpg
Ford-Mustang-003.jpg

Chevy-Impala-001.jpg
Chevy-Impala-002.jpg
Chevy-Impala-003.jpg
```

I would like to sort these into subfolders:

```
/Mustang
/Impala
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using prename (perl renamer)

```
prename 'if(/(.+?)-(.+?)-(.*)/){mkdir $2; $_="$2/$_"}' *.jpg
```

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks! Now would using the first part of the filename be as simple as changing the "2" to "1"?

Comment: yes: each parenthesis grout captures a matching string available under `$1`, `$2`...

Comment: does this call `mkdir` for each file ? if so, shouldn't it use **`-p`** flag ?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga, this is the perl function `mkdir` not the bash mkdir. Internally the function returns false is dir already exists. In this case there is no problem in ignoring it.

Comment: One liners are all right, but consider adding at least some explanation.

Answer (score 6):

The obvious answer:

Just make the directories and put the files in them.

```
mkdir Mustang Impala
mv *Mustang*.jpg Mustang/
mv *Impala*.jpg Impala/
```

This is called *file globbing*; it's a shell feature.

---

If you have huge numbers of files and need to make many different directories to accommodate them, try [JJoao's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321289/135943).

Comment: Wildcard, OP wants to move files _into a sub-folder based on filename part_ so it's kinda obvious that the above is just an example. I know you can do better than this...

Comment: @don_crissti, I would *think* this is just an example, if I hadn't been looking at questions from new users all morning.  ;)  I upvoted the other answer, but I'll leave this here in case someone is looking for the stupid-simple solution.

Comment: As someone in the process of learning the commands, this is helpful as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would split thw filename using awk `awk {split $0, a, "-"; mkdir a[1]; mv $0 a[1]/}` if you want to rename you could do this with the mv program